# ASP.NET MVC detect browser close

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I searched for this a lot and I always get similar answer asking to write code in javascript like below

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { console.log("Hello") ; }
```

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with Login Page, many cshtml files and one shared Controller class and action methods in controller class returns partial views (cshtml file) and each partial view has its own javascript file. I also have Layout.cshtml which is shared by all Partial Views and Layout is null for Login Page which means my Login Page doesnot share my Layout.cshtml. For example like below

_Layout.cshtml

AdminController.cs

Login.cshtml ( doesnot have any layout )

Customer.cshtml, customer.js

Seller.cshtml, seller.js

We are using microsoft OWIN with our custom code for authorization and authentication. So I am exploring to solve my issue using javascript.

Now I am trying to find out when user clicked X on browser so that I can clear the cookie that eventually logs him/her out and next time when they launch my app in browser they are directed to Login Page.

I tried above solution in Layout.cshtml and also javascript files.

In Layout.cshtml it is fired each time when I go from one page to another.

In customeer.js file, it is fired when I move away from customer page.

Basically I need to know where I need to place above solution or else find out whether user moved from one page to other page in application and is still in my application against when user clicked X and closed browser

Comment: You can create a cookie that will expire at the end of the user's browser session. When you create a cookie without setting a date, this is the default behavior. I do not know how to configure OWIN auth to accomplish this but it might be worth looking into creating a cookie that will expire and clear on its own rather than writing javascript to do this manually.

Comment: @Jonathan.... Thanks...I will look into this... You can create a cookie that will expire at the end of the user's browser session in OWIN... Irrespective of that is there a way on client side we can detect when user is closing a browser...

Comment: In my Startup.Auth.cs I am using app.UseCookieAuthentication with CookieAuthenticationOptions, and I donot see anything that says expires after session ends. I will research more.

Comment: I too am interested in how to detect the browser closing. I am not familiar with OWIN cookies, but you should be able to set the ExpiresTimeSpan option of the CookieAuthenticationOptions to 0 to create a cookie that will expire after the browser session ends. At least that would be my best guess to force the Auth cookie to expire at the end of the session.